# Method Return NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Hello all i have a method in nsobject ie

```
 -(NSDictionary*)DictionaryValues:(NSArray*)arrayList{
    //calling delegate method....
    return (nsmutabledictionary*);
}
```

Here how to return dictionary when calling this method.

i used dictionaryProductInformation but its not working.

Comment: Where do you allocate or create the dictionary?

Comment: Show how you allocate and attempt to return it.

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
 mutableDictionary dictionaryProductInformation;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things:

- Please adhere to the Objective-C guidelines, which say that method names should begin with a lowercase letter
- If you always return an `NSMutableDictionary`, then you may state that in the return value declaration (but that may not be necessary, your choice)
- If you create the dictionary inside the method, and your method name does not begin with **new**, **init** or **copy**, then please also adhere to the guidelines and return an *autoreleased* object

That said, your method should look like:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *) dictionaryValues:(NSArray*)arrayList{
    // ...
    NSMutableDictionary *yourDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    // do something with your dictionary

    return yourDictionary;
}
```